# Not able to connect to database while implementing frontend and backend in Kubernetes

Tags: php, kubernetes

I have frontend container running with below php code;

```
<?php
$hn=file_get_contents('/var/secrets/hostname.txt');
$hn=str_replace("\n", "", $hn);
$pass=file_get_contents('/var/secrets/password.txt');
$pass=str_replace("\n", "", $pass);
$cname=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$hostname=$hn;
$username='root';
$password=$pass;
$dbname='test';
$usertable='testuser';
$con=mysqli_connect($hostname,$username, $password) OR DIE ('Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.');
mysqli_select_db($con,$dbname);
$query = "select * from testuser";
$result = $con->query($query) or die("Not Updated!");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["name"] . "<td> " . $row["email"] . "</tr> ";
}
$con->close();
?>
```

I have hostname name and password saved in text file as mentioned above on frontend container. I have metioned **hostname as SeriveName**. Please find below sample backend service,  here backend service name is "userdatabase-service". Same I have mentioned in hostname.txt on frontend container.

```
    apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-11-13T12:01:25Z
  labels:
    app: userdatabase
  name: userdatabase-service
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "32448"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/userdatabase-service
  uid: d85cf471-e73b-11e8-8506-42010aa60fca
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.7.255.80
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - nodePort: 30198
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 3306
  selector:
    app: userdatabase
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 35.228.105.176
```

But while accessing frontend service which pulls record from database gives message: Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.

I tried with Ingress Ip but still it gives same error. 
Can you please guide here?
Regards,
Vikas

Comment: Well, unless you put `userdatabase-service:80` into `/var/secrets/hostname.txt`, `mysqli_connect` will try to use the default port (which I **strongly** suspect is not `80`) and thus nope right out. Furthermore, hostnames are not secrets, and so if you just pulled the hostname out of the environment, it would be one less moving part to manage: `$hostname = getenv("USERDATABASE_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST").":".getenv("USERDATABASE_SERVICE_SERVICE_PORT")`

Comment: HI Matthew, Thank you for valuable suggestion, I mentioned Port after the host-name and it worked. I thought it will take port 80 automatically. Thank  you again :)

Comment: Could you please start marking your questions as answered please?

Answer (score 1):

This was solved in the comments by @[Matthew L Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225016/matthew-l-daniel). The connection string was being formed with 'userdatabase-service' but without any explicit port. It worked when the port 80 was added to the connection string.